# One spinner showing correctly a default value and the other not

Tags: android, spinner

I have got two spinners that receive a default value as a variable from another view. The first one is working fine but the second one not (it shows position 0 as the default value). Here is my code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lista_origen);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Main2Activity.this,
R.array.l_source, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(l_source));

Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lista_destino);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Main2Activity.this,
R.array.l_source, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
spinner2.setSelection(adapter2.getPosition(l_target));
```

`l_target` and `l_source` are the variables and they are correctly sent from the previous view to this one.

I would be grateful if you could find what and why is failing.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I Think in Spinner2 ArrayAdapter, you have taken R.array.l_source. check the code once

Comment: Have you applied different styles on R.id.lista_origen compared to R.id.lista_destino in your layout?

Comment: Thank you @RameshR, I will check the code now

Comment: No @JaspervandeKlundert same styles for both. Thank you for the answer